Request.session in django doesnt pass through ajax unless i refresh the page
Request.session in django doesnt pass through ajax unless i refresh the page
request.session remains the old one unless i hit refresh to the page
any help would appreciated
` $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#specialty_form").on('change', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        function getCSRFToken() {
            return $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': getCSRFToken()
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/specialty',
            data: {
                specialty: $("#specialty").val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoke: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
            },
        })
    })
});`


Request.session works only when the request is made through the browser, because browser is responsible for maintaining client side session cookies. For AJAX requests you need to pass something like a user id to identify the User who's making the request.

can u give an example in the code ???

Are you using Jinja templates? i.e. displaying the html templates using return render(request,"*.html")

Any properly implemented HTTP client should be able to fill those headers. This answer is based on a false premise.
